# how xoring calculates bitsparity?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift

```
/*
 * bitParity - returns 1 if x contains an odd number of 0's
 *   Examples: bitParity(5) = 0, bitParity(7) = 1
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max ops: 20
 *   Rating: 4
 */
int bitParity(int x) { //XORing two numbers returns a number with same bit parity. 
                       //Keep shifting half of our number until reduced to 1 bit simple case
  x = ( x >> 16 ) ^ x;
  x = ( x >> 8 ) ^ x;
  x = ( x >> 4 ) ^ x;
  x = ( x >> 2 ) ^ x;
  x = ( x >> 1) ^ x;

  return (x & 1);
}
```

hi, I tried to solve this problem, and failed.

so I searched the answer on google.

most of the solutions available on google differed from each other,

but in this bitsparity problem, answers are all the same (using xor)

I know it is wrong asking how this or that code works,

so I want to know the mechanisms or the idea.

it would be really helpful if you give me any glimpse of idea.

cannot solving this problem for days, need some help

```
int bitParity(int x) {
  int x1 = ( x >> 28 ) ^ x;
  int x2 = ( x >> 24 ) ^ x1;
  int x3 = ( x >> 20 ) ^ x2;
  int x4 = ( x >> 16 ) ^ x3;
  int x5 = ( x >> 12 ) ^ x4;
  int x6 = ( x >> 8 ) ^ x5;
  int x7 = ( x >> 4 ) ^ x6;
  int x8 = ( x >> 2 ) ^ x7;
  int x9 = ( x >> 1 ) ^ x8;
  return (x9 & 1);
}
```

above code does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a debugger, you could follow the flow of statements line by line:

```
x = ( x >> 16 ) ^ x;
```

Computes a bitwise `xor` of the higher (most significant) 16 bits and the lower (least significant) 16 bits. Only the lower 16 bits of the result are taken into account further on. The upper half of the integer is shifted down/right by 16 bit positions.

```
  x = ( x >> 8 ) ^ x;
```

Computes the bitwise `xor` of the higher 8 and the lower 8 bits of the previous result.

```
  x = ( x >> 4 ) ^ x;
  x = ( x >> 2 ) ^ x;
  x = ( x >> 1) ^ x
```

The original 32 bits are collapsed/folded to 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 bits to collect non-equal bit positions. Eventually, the remaining single bit indicates if there was an odd number of set bits in the original 32-bit integer.

If two halfs of a integer are xor'ed, bit positions with identical value result in a 0 bit, while bit positions of opposite values result in a 1 bit. Therefore, the resulting 1 bits represent bit position pairs in the original integer, which are unequal. Pairs of such "odd pairs" cancel out.

```
x & 1
```

masks the least-significant bit of `x` and is 1 for odd `x` or 0 for even `x`.

Comment: thanks for your help. honestly at first, I also couldn`t understand your answer. but now it make sense. I understand this solution with recursive-thinking. your expression "cancel-out" is great. so >>28, >>24, >>20, ... >>4, >>2, >>1 , &1 may also work, though its inefficient

Comment: sir, can you explain why the above code I have edited not working? I applied the same principle which you have told me.

Comment: Your second code is quite different. You introduced additional variables but still use x in the shift. Apart from that, you do not stick to the "div 2" recursion. Use a debugger to spot the differences.